# How do we change SharePoint Online domain name?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

We just purchased a domain name (www.mydomain.net) and we need to change it from the SharePoint Online domain (www.mydomain.sharepoint.com)

For example:
www.mydomain.sharepoint.com -> www.mydomain.net

How is this possible with SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online Public Websites are discontinued by microsoft.
[public sites are discontinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued)

You can just use domain name to customize your email address like user@mydomain.net but you cant have a share point site like //mydomain.net what you can do is keep that site with your provider and make a redirect to  www.mydomain.sharepoint.com

Or host the public site with Wordpress etc and make a button saying Login to  mydomain Sharepoint site.
Redirect:
https://www.godaddy.com/help/create-url-redirects-in-my-web-and-classic-hosting-account-5120